# ActiveMQ Artemis equivalent to ActiveMQ Classic DestinationStatistics

Tags: activemq-artemis

Is there an equivalent to ActiveMQ Classic's `DestinationStatistics` in ActiveMQ Artemis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a whole management API which includes both `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.management.QueueControl` and `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.management.AddressControl`. These can be used to get statistics.